# Call a web-service under current user credentials

Tags: wcf, windows-authentication, defaultnetworkcredentials

I have a custom WCF web-service confugured with windows authentication and a WPF client application that needs to call the former. The service checks the username and pull some specific data from a database. So I have to call the service using credentials of the user running the application.

The problem is my service is hosted under another site with windows authentication and users can authenticate there with another accounts. Windows (or IE?) caches last accout used and then my client app uses it too!

Example:

I enter the website under "MYDOMAIN\AdminUser"

I run following code (from the client app, it's not web code)

```
var client = new TestServiceClient();
var currentUser = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent(); // just informative field nothing more, i don't use it anyhow
// currentUser.Name = "MYDOMAIN\\MyUserName" - it's current value, i'm not trying to set it
client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
var data = client.GetTestData();
```

Service gets called by "MYDOMAIN\AdminUser"..

I know I can create NetworkCredential with name and password but I then will have to store it somewhere, encript it and so on..

To clarify the problem: client process running under one account calls the service under another account by itself, just becouse windows supplies the call with another credentials under the hood.

Comment: I don't fully understand second paragraph. What is the problem with hosting the service on another server and what does it mean "with another account"?

Comment: Well, do you have a corporate domain account and portals of any sort at your work? Sharepoint for instance. If you do, you can enter the portal under your account (something like corp\ladislav i guess). But you can enter using another user account, admin account for example (let's say it is corp\portaladmin) if you know a password. Windows then remembers last used and cache it in Credential Vault. Then it transparently applies it (at least at .net level) to every network communication with the same server. That's the problem.

Comment: Still don't get it - I have never seen such behavior and I have several domain accounts. If I access the site using Windows Integrated security current account is used.

Comment: Try run following code on any page where your user name is displayed:`WebClient client = new WebClient();
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            String str = client.DownloadString("http://www.yourportal.com/somepage.aspx");` Then you will see in html in str what user name is used. You should notice that this code use cached accound, last one you entered in IE (I think it matters, becouse other browsers store their password ccache separately).

Comment: So you are not using integrated authentication - you must fill in user and password. In such case it will be the browser problem and I'm affraid you will not solve it on the server. I'm going to delete my answer because I didn't understand your problem when I wrote it.